# Count capture groups ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex in my ruby script with a couple of capture groups. Here's a snippet of it: `/^cost:\s(\d)+\sitems:\s`
And I'm capturing the digit that comes right after cost. I have more capture groups later on but I don't know how many will get captured. Depends on the input text file. I know the way to access capture groups is with:

```
$1, $2 etc etc
```

But I don't know how many get captured. Is there a way to find out the number of groups that were captured and iterate through it maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might use [`MatchData#captures`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/MatchData.html#method-i-captures):

```
▶ mtch = /(\w)(\w)(\w)/.match 'hello'
#⇒ #<MatchData "hel" 1:"h" 2:"e" 3:"l">
▶ mtch.captures
#⇒ [
#  [0] "h",
#  [1] "e",
#  [2] "l"
# ]
```

Also note, that you actually capture *a first digit in a sequence* only. To capture all of them, move `+` inside parentheses:

```
#           ⇓
/^cost:\s(\d+)\sitems:\s.../
```

Comment: Thanks! Question: I tried to iterate through it using mtch.each {|x| puts x} but got hit with the .each not defined error. Why is that? Is a for loop the only way to iterate through it then?

Comment: You must be kidding: `mtch.captures.each { |e| print e } #⇒ hel`. The glitch is somewhere else.

Comment: Oh I'm dumb. Didn't put captures. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the scan method if you think you have non-deterministic split with a regex: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan

Comment: What is a "non-deterministic split"?

Comment: Poor wording perhaps. I mean that I use Ruby's Regex object when I have to match something that has a known amount of capture groups.  But when I want to match a list of things where I don't know how many items I have, then I use Scan.